# Ajuda para executar esse desafio proposto "requisição https"

Tags: javascript, java, html, http

sou iniciante em programação então ainda tenho dúvidas bobas, a respeito de alguns assuntos em programação, poderiam me ajudar com o desafio da imagem? imagem do desafio proposto

> [Desafio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSzDH.png)

"Queremos que você faça uma requisição HTTP para o endereço <"https://userhashcodeserver.uk.r.appspot.com/hashCodeServer?nome=Exemplo&email=XXX@gmail.com&cpf=XXX.XXX.XXX-XX"> essa requisição deve ser do tipo POST e deve conter em seus parâmetros as seguintes informações :

Seu nome completo sem espaços,
seu e-mail e
seu cpf,"

O que está sendo pedido? como devo proceder? me deem uma luz por favor.

estou iniciando e buscando ajuda para obtenção do resultado.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta?cb=1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, pelo o entendi é pra você fazer o envio dos dados por usa requisição. Não sei qual é a linguagem. vou deixa aqui um exemplo em AJAX.

**cdn jquery** : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery

//Lembra de colocar cnd do jquey ou baixar o mesmo

```
$.ajax({

method: "POST",
url: "https://userhashcodeserver.uk.r.appspot.com/hashCodeServer",
data: {nome: "lucas",email: "lucas@gmail.com", cpf:"000.000.000-00"}

});
```